# Generating combinations that fulfill certain restrictions for graphs

Tags: algorithms, graphs, combinatorics

I am working with graphs, let's say I have 4 nodes, named **A, B, C, D**, each node has to be connected a certain number of times to the other nodes.

**A: 3, B: 3, C: 2, D: 2**

This means that **A** and **B** are connected three times and **C** and **D** two times. All the possibles pairs generated are the following:

**(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D)**

Now I need to generate all combinations of **5** pairs where **A** and **B** appear three times and **C** and **D** two.

This is an example of an acceptable combination:
**(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D)**

Here the set fulfills this condition: **A: 3, B: 3, C: 2, D: 2**
With **A** and **B** appearing three times and **C** and **D** only two.

This is an example of an unacceptable combination:
**(A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (C, D)**
Here the set doesn't fulfill this condition: **A: 3, B: 3, C: 2, D: 2**
With **A** and **C** appearing three times and **B** and **D** only two.

Anyone know how I could create an algorithm that gets me only the combinations of pairs that fulfill this condition?

Comment: Since you have just $4$ nodes you can just exhaustively check all $2^6 = 64$ subsets of $\{ (A, B), (A, C), (A, D), (B, C), (B, D), (C, D) \}$.

Comment: @Andreu Please do not update the question with answers. A question should be a question, especially when there is one or more answers. You can always post an answer if you want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is addressed in Kim, Toroczkai, Miklós, Erdős and Székely, [On realizing all simple graphs with a given
degree sequence](https://cse.msu.edu/%7Ecse835/Papers/On%20realizing%20all%20simple%20graphs%20with%20a%20given.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an algorithm I've coded myself that does what I asked:

````python
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain, repeat, count, islice
from collections import Counter


def unique_combinations(iterable, r):

    def repeat_chain(values, counts):
        return chain.from_iterable(map(repeat, values, counts))

    def unique_combinations_from_value_counts(values, counts, r):
        n = len(counts)
        indices = list(islice(repeat_chain(count(), counts), r))
        if len(indices) < r:
            return
        while True:
            yield tuple(values[i] for i in indices)
            for i, j in zip(reversed(range(r)), repeat_chain(reversed(range(n)), reversed(counts))):
                if indices[i] != j:
                    break
            else:
                return
            j = indices[i] + 1
            for i, j in zip(range(i, r), repeat_chain(count(j), counts[j:])):
                indices[i] = j

    values, counts = zip(*Counter(iterable).items())
    return unique_combinations_from_value_counts(values, counts, r)


def havel_hakimi(deg_sequence, edge_list=[], i=0):

    node = deg_sequence.pop(0)
    a = []
    for j in range(len(deg_sequence)):
        if deg_sequence[j] <= 2:
            factor = deg_sequence[j]
        else:
            factor = 2
        a += factor * [(i, j+i+1)]

    i += 1
    for combination in unique_combinations(a, node):
        deg_sequence_copy = deg_sequence.copy()
        edge_list_copy = edge_list.copy()
        edge_list_copy += combination
        subtract_vertices_list = [item[1]-i for item in combination]

        for vertex in subtract_vertices_list:
            deg_sequence_copy[vertex] -= 1

        while deg_sequence_copy[-1] == 0 and len(deg_sequence_copy) > 1:
            deg_sequence_copy.pop(-1)

        if not all(v == 0 for v in deg_sequence_copy) and len(deg_sequence_copy) > 1:
            havel_hakimi(deg_sequence_copy, edge_list_copy,  i)

        if all(v == 0 for v in deg_sequence_copy):
            print(edge_list_copy)
            pass

        else:
            pass
```
````